# WPF Animation Relative Values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to learn about Storyboards and animation in WPF. I have a very simple question which I cannot seem to answer.

I have a rectangle that is placed in a grid. I am trying to move the rectangle from one side of the grid to the other side. I can get the rectangle to move successfully. However the issue is that I'm specifying the From & To values. So in my code below I have hard coded the from (50) & to (300) values. What I want to happen is for the rectangle to go to the other side of the grid without me hard coding a value. Because if a user resizes the window the values I put in will be a waste of time.

```
 <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"  
                                             From="50"
                                             To="300"
                                             Duration="0:0:5"/>
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                                To="Yellow"
                                BeginTime="0:0:5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When animating sizes/locations with `Storyboard`s, always use the `ActualWidth` and/or `Actualheight` properties instead of the usual `Width` and `Height` properties because the `Width` and `Height` properties can often have `NaN` (Not a number) values which will blow up when the `Storyboard` tries to access it/them.

For this animation, you'll need to declare the `Name` property of the parent element because we'll reference it in the `Storyboard`. Try this and let me know how you get on:

```
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="50" 
To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ParentContainer}" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" To="Yellow" 
BeginTime="0:0:5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Width property, you could use ScaleTransform of RenderTransform. This will let you scale according to the parent element and not the width itself. See the example underneath and see if it works...

```
<Rectangle Height="70" Fill="Green">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.2"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"  
                                        From="0.2"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0:0:5"/>
                        <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                        To="Yellow"
                        BeginTime="0:0:5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```